# How to find directions of region on $\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

> Let $S=\{x:x_1+2x_2\le 4\}$.
>   Find the extreme points and directions of S.
>   Can you represent any point in $S$ as a convex combination of its extreme points
>   plus a nonnegative linear combination of its extreme directions?

There is no extreme points. (Seen in another question)

Now I am having trouble finding the directions of $S$ which by definition is $d\in\mathbb R^n$ such that $\forall x\in S ,\ \forall \lambda\ge 0:x+\lambda d\in S$.

So take $d=(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2,\lambda\ge0,\ s=(x_1,x_2)\in S.$

Then we should get $d\lambda+s\in S.$

Thus do we try to solve this $(\lambda x,\lambda y)+(x_1,x_2)\le2-x_1/2$ $?\ \ ?$

---

I feel lost, help please!

Comment: Just draw a picture?

Comment: OK, but the picture should tell you everything you need to know in order to write a formal solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The domain $S$ is a half-plane bounded by a line, whose equation is $x_1+2x_2=4$ (draw a picture).

If you start at a point in $S$ and move towards the boundary, you will eventually hit it and get out of $S$. That means you're not following a "direction".

If you move parallel to the boundary, of away from it, then you will never get out of $S$. This means you are now following a direction.

So you need to understand which vectors "look towards the boundary" and which don't.

Comment: So the directions will be defined as follows: for every point $x=(x_1,x_2)$ in $S$ such that $\lambda d||x_2=2-x_1/2$ ?

Comment: Yes, all vectors $d$ that are parallel to the line $x_2=2-x_1/2$, but also all vectors that "look away from the line". Because remember, $\lambda$ has to be non-negative, so you don't move backwards.